# share the screen in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I would like to share my screen with one of my friends from Ubuntu 16.04, I have seen many videos before asking the question here, but none of them helped me. So can any one here help out on this. (step by step if possible :))

Answer (score 0):

The "right" answer is to setup XRDP and switch your desktop environment.  The "easy" answer is to install [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/).  It's free for personal use and works great!